# Table with mapped object only getting the last value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an `data` object with an array of data that I mapped inside a table. It looks fine, but when I console.log() the id of the item of any of the table´s rows, it always get the value of the last item of the array.

This is my data:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
        id: "uuid1",
        name: "Guilherme",
        phone: "11 11111-1111",
        address: "rua tal tal tal",
    },
    {
        id: "uuid2",
        name: "Lucas",
        phone: "22 22222-2222",
        address: "avenida tal tal tal",
    },
    {
        id: "uuid3",
        name: "Unipar",
        phone: "33 33333-3333",
        address: "edifício tal tal tal",
    },
]);

const columns = [
    { description: "Nome", width: "50%" },
    { description: "Telefone", width: "25%" },
    { description: "Endereço", width: "25%" },
    { description: "Ações", width: "0%" },
];
```

And this is the content of my table (I'm using react material-ui components):

```
<TableBody>
  {data.map((item) => (
    <TableRow key={item.id}>
      <TableCell>{item.name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{item.phone}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{item.address}</TableCell>
      <TableCell align="center">
        <IconButton onClick={handleClick}>
          <List />
        </IconButton>
        <Menu
          id={item.id}
          key={item.id}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          keepMounted
          open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
          onClose={handleClose}
          elevation={0}
          getContentAnchorEl={null}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: "bottom",
            horizontal: "center",
          }}
          transformOrigin={{
            vertical: "top",
            horizontal: "center",
          }}
        >

          <MenuItem onClick={() => handleEdit(item.id)}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Edit className={classes.iconsColor} />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Editar" />
          </MenuItem>

          <MenuItem onClick={() => handleDelete(item.id)}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Delete className={classes.iconsColor} />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Excluir" />
          </MenuItem>

        </Menu>
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ))}
</TableBody>
```

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-wiles-8fzd7?file=/src/table.tsx

Comment: where/how are you using `console.log` to output the id?

Comment: inside `handleEdit` and `handleDelete`, sorry for not explaining it clearly.

Comment: you passed item.id to ``handleEdit`` and ``handleDelete``. It will be loged. I mean only one id  when click thoes MenuItems  :-)

Comment: my problem is: the table shows 3 rows of data, each one with its own values (including the id), but when i call the methods they always get the id of the last item.

Comment: Code shown appears to be fine. Show us the part with the logging.

Comment: Can you share your code to stackblitz or something?

Comment: sure, here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-wiles-8fzd7?file=/src/table.tsx

Comment: All your `Menu` component share the same `anchorEl` value. If you inspect the DOM you will see that you are opening all menus at the same time, hence the last one to render is always the one on top. You need to extract your Menu.

Comment: The reason it always log 'uuid' in the console is because menu with the id uuird4 is rendered last and it overlaps the other menus. all your  menu share the same ancherEl so they will render on the same position. And you can only see the last menu.(uuid4). when you close your menu, they will close together, And click another button, they will render that position, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it always log 'uuid4' in the console, is because menu with the id uuid4 is rendered last and it overlaps the other menus. all your menu share the same ancherEl so they will render on the same position. And you can only see the last menu.(uuid4). when you close your menu, they will close together, And click another button, they will render that position, and so on.

I think it can help you.

```
const [selectedItemIndex, setSelectedItemIndex] = React.useState("");
const handleClick = (event, id) => {
  setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  setSelectedItemIndex(id);
};

<Menu
  id={item.id}
  key={item.id}
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  keepMounted
  open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
  onClose={handleClose}
  elevation={0}
  getContentAnchorEl={null}
  anchorOrigin={{
    vertical: "bottom",
    horizontal: "center"
  }}
  transformOrigin={{
    vertical: "top",
    horizontal: "center"
  }}
>
  <MenuItem onClick={() => handleView(selectedItemIndex)}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <Search className={classes.iconsColor} />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Visualizar" />
  </MenuItem>

  <MenuItem onClick={() => handleEdit(selectedItemIndex)}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <Edit className={classes.iconsColor} />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Editar" />
  </MenuItem>

  <MenuItem onClick={() => handleDelete(selectedItemIndex)}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <Delete className={classes.iconsColor} />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Excluir" />
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Please confirm this url https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-tereshkova-xzynj?file=/src/table.tsx:4055-5625.
It renders all menu on the same position too. But the id will be you clicked.